# $\operatorname{Aut} (G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut} (H)$ then is it necessary that $G$ is isomorphic to $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $\operatorname{Aut} (G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut} (H)$ then is it necessary that $G$ is isomorphic to $H$?

My answer is no.
$\operatorname{Aut} (\mathbb{Z)}$ is isomorphic to $Z_2$ and $\operatorname{Aut} (Z_3)$ is also isomorphic to $U(3)$, which is isomorphic to $Z_2$. But $\mathbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $Z_3.$ Correct? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I meant$Z_3$

Comment: @Derek Holt I edited it to$Z_3$. Am I correct now?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Also there's no need for introducing $U(3)$, $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ has exactly two elements, thus it has to be $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @freakish thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides your example, there is even an example with *finite* groups, as
$$
{\rm Aut}(S_3)\cong {\rm Aut}(C_2\times C_2)\cong S_3,
$$
but $S_3$ is of course not isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$.

Answer (score 2):

As another example, both the trivial group $Id$ and the cyclic group of order two $C_2$ have trivial automorphism group:
$$\operatorname{Aut}(Id)\cong Id\cong\operatorname{Aut(C_2)}$$

This is the smallest possible example...

(These are the only two groups $G$ with $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong Id$. See [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Trivial_automorphism_group_implies_trivial_or_order_two) for a proof.)

Answer (score 1):

You can even use non-isomorphic finite groups of the same order.  The smallest example is $Aut(C_4\times C_2)\cong Aut(D_8)\cong D_8$.